# Django adding related object to instance of a parent

Tags: django, django-models

RoR refugee, learning Django here.
I have an application with related models, Project and Workstream. I need to create new Workstream objects related to a Project (Project can have many workstreams). I have the logic and relations for this working fine, but when I try to create a method in the Project class to add a workstream to a Project instance and provide default values, I cannot get it to work. I have the function, but get an attribute error 'Manager' object has no attribute 'add'. When I research managers, I can find no references involving functions adding to a model, only involving limiting querysets. I suspect I am not doing things The Django Way in my approach.

Wrote classes and functions, got errors, researched those, found nothing useful.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('NS', 'Not Started'),
        ('IP', 'In Process'),
        ('PR', 'Pending Review'),
        ('CP', 'Complete'),
    )
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey('clients.Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        # Return the name of the Project.
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def add_workstream(self, ws_name='New Workstream', ws_desc='TBD'):
        """Add a workstream.

        Include optional arguments for name, description and status.
        """
        from workstreams.models import Workstream
        new_ws = Workstream(project_id=self.project_id,
                            name=ws_name,
                            description=ws_desc)
        new_ws.save()

# Complete workstreams/models.py

from django.db import models
import tasks
import artifacts


class Workstream(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('NS', 'Not Started'),
        ('IP', 'In Process'),
        ('PR', 'Pending Review'),
        ('CP', 'Complete'),
    )
    workstream_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    project_id = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the Django console:

```
>>> test=Project.objects.get(name='Auditron')
>>> test.add_workstream()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/srummel/DEV/auditron/auditron/projects/models.py", line 28, in add_workstream
    from workstreams.models import Workstream
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'add'
>>>
```

I expected to create a new workstream instance linked to my Project with the default values populated.
I understand the problem is with my manager - I am asking if my approach is correct, and if so, if anyone has any examples of what a manager implementing an 'add' function for a related class would be. My hindbrain is telling me I am making a fundamental architecture error, but not sure what it is. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This error is not coming from any of the code you have posted. Where are you calling `add`?

Comment: Apologies, the function is 'add_workstream'.

Comment: No I see that, but that error is not happening in the code of that method. It seems to be happening as a result of importing workstreams.models; you should show where in that file you are calling `.add`.

Comment: The error appeared in the Django console - I created a Project object called 'test' then called 'test.add_workstream()' and got the AttributeError.

Comment: Once again, please show the full workstreams/models.py file including the place where it calls `.add`.

Comment: Workstreams does not call .add_workstream, the method is in the Project class. Project.add_workstream() -> new Workstream linked to that Project instance. I defined the function as a class method in the Project class and called it on my 'test' Project object. I fear I misunderstand what you are asking for..?

Comment: I am asking you post the contents of your workstream/models.py file. Your `add_workstream` method imports that file, and the result of importing it is an error, because for some reason something in that file is calling `add` on a Manager. We cannot tell why until we see that whole file.

Comment: The other possibility is that the code you have shown was edited since you imported it in the shell, and therefore the traceback is pointing to the wrong line. Either way, *you need to show some code that is calling a method named `add()`*, which you have not done so far.

Comment: I re-pasted the entire contents of workstreams/models.py into the code space above. Thank you!

Comment: So the problem is not there either. But there is something, somewhere in your code that is calling an `add()` method. I suggest you use your editor to search your project for the string `"add("`.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this as the solution was both non-intuitive and completely unrelated to the code I posted. When using the interactive python interpreter in Django, you cant just re-import the class, you have to shut down the interpreter and restart it. I tried multiple times to add simple placeholder methods to troubleshoot where things were falling apart, and I got AttributeErrors on everything.

Solution is:
At the python shell prompt:
Type: exit() 
Type: python manage.py shell 
re-run code and it works...

I appreciate those who took the time to read and respond.

Answer (score -1):

Your 'add_workstream' function needs to be refactored when creating an instance of Workstream to be as follows:

```
@staticmethod
def add_workstream(self, ws_name='New Workstream', ws_desc='TBD'):
    new_ws = Workstream.objects.create(project_id=self.project_id, 
                                       name=ws_name,
                                       description=ws_desc)
```

1. It needs to be a 'static_method' not 'class_method'
2. no need for new_ws.save()
3. Add '.objects.create' after the class name

Comment: Neither of these are necessary, nor would they cause the op's error.

Comment: Maybe the answer was not clear enough. The main issue was the absence of '.objects.create' after the class name, as shown in the snippet. However, the 2 other points are enhancements in the code.

Comment: But that is not true either. It is perfectly valid to create a model item by instantiating it directly and then saving it.

Comment: I tried this solution (thank you BTW) and got the same error. There is an issue in the Manager, but not sure what that fix would look like.